# NullPointerException on createViewFromResource in a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I am working on a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) for `Android`. I am following some of the code discussed [here](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences), which uses a [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) object. My `preferences.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/prefs_app" >

      <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/gps_freq_main_key"
        android:title="@string/gps_freq_main_title"
        android:summary="@string/gps_freq_main_summary"
        android:entries="@array/gps_freq_main_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/gps_freq_main_entryValues"
        android:defaultValue="every second (recommended)" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/prefs_other">

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="@string/app_info_key"
            android:title="@string/app_info_title"
            android:summary="@string/app_info_summary">

          <Preference
            android:key="@string/app_copyright_key"
            android:title="@string/app_copyright_title"
            android:summary="@string/app_copyright_summary" />

          <Preference
            android:key="@string/app_version_key"
            android:title="@string/app_version_title" />

    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

All of the strings mentioned are defined in `res/values/strings.xml`. The two arrays are defined in `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <integer-array name="gps_freq_main_entries">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>60</item>
    <item>120</item>
    <item>300</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>900</item>
    <item>1200</item>
  </integer-array>
  <string-array name="gps_freq_main_entryValues">
    <item>every second (recommended)</item>
    <item>2 seconds</item>
    <item>3 seconds</item>
    <item>4 seconds</item>
    <item>5 seconds</item>
    <item>10 seconds</item>
    <item>20 seconds</item>
    <item>30 seconds</item>
    <item>1 minute</item>
    <item>2 minutes</item>
    <item>5 minutes</item>
    <item>10 minutes</item>
    <item>15 minutes</item>
    <item>30 minutes</item>
  </string-array>

</resources>
```

The problem arises when I select this `ListPreference` (the Activity launches correctly, and all other preferences work). There is no code in my [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) that affects this `ListPreference`. Here is my `logcat`:

```
08-24 15:34:49.428: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:351)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1269)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1117)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1030)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:698)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-24 15:34:49.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try a clean build.  Sometimes the generated files get out of sync.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I already did, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I also tried deleting the old installation of the app to clear any data, but this is still happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this problem with a different application. To solve it, I used a string-array instead of an integer array. I'm not sure why this is needed, but it worked.

Comment: +1 Indeed, some ninja exceptions (with no way of tracing them to the array being one of ints) also occur if you try to use an int array as the singleChoiceItems in an AlertDialog.